# Pandas DataFrame - Why does my Correlation Matrix have a shape of (0, 0)?

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe

Despite the shape of my `DataFrame` (`df`) is `(100_000, 13)`, the correlation matrix has a shape of `(0, 0)`. Hence getting `ValueError` when I try to plot it using `Seaborn`'s `heatmap`. What could be the reason?

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
corr = df.corr()
sns.heatmap(corr, xticklabels=corr.columns.values, yticklabels=corr.columns.values)
```

Comment: What does `df.info()` show? You probably don't have any numerical columns.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It display the 13 columns and all of them have that brief data description: `100000 non-null object`. Actually, I do have numerical columns as 7 of the 13 columns are numerical.

Comment: `object` implies that they are not treated as numerical. They are either strings or Python ints/floats/decimals instead of numpy ints/floats. You can change their types with `df[list_of_cols] = df[list_of_cols].astype('float')`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now works as it is expected. Could you please post your comment as an answer to let me mark it as the answer of my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataFrame.corr` method only considers columns that are numerical. If for some reason all your columns are of dtype object, you will get an empty DataFrame. To resolve this, you can cast the columns that you want to compute the correlation on as floats:

```
df[list_of_cols] = df[list_of_cols].astype('float')
```